# Nested Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

On our website the client can add different items into the footer columns, ie a text box. We wanted to be able to keep the code for these different items in one partial view, as the items are used in other areas of the site and want to keep code duplication to a minimum.

I was wondering if it possible to nest a Partial View within a foreach statement and then pass an if statement based on the parent foreach.

I have the following code in a partial view called Three_Column_Footer:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
        var root = Model.Content.Site();
        var thefooter = root.FirstChild("footer").Children();
    }
    <footer class="footer color-main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                @foreach(var foot in thefooter){
                    var childcol = foot.Children;
                        <div class="col-6">
                            @foreach(var item in childcol){
                                @Html.Partial("Footers/FooterStubs", item)
                            }
                        </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

I need someway of getting the above foreach to be recognised in the Partial called FooterStubs. Can this be done with an `@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<IPublishedContent>` or a `Model.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>` - if so how?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the content of `FooterStubs`, particularly the first 6 lines.

Comment: There currently is only this line in FooterStubs, as thats the bit that is confusing me: @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<IPublishedContent>

Comment: so u have two partials view and you want to give reference of one into another?or u have two PV(partial view) with reference of each other means they are calling each other...?quite confusing if above is ur code for 'Three_Column_Footer'

Answer (score 0):

The `Partial` method has an overload that accepts `additionalViewData`. You can utilize this to provide any additional context you need the partial to have:

```
@Html.Partial("Footers/FooterStubs", item, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData)
{
    { "foot": foot }
});
```

Then in your partial:

```
@{
    var foot = ViewData["foot"] as YourFootClass;
}
```

I'm not sure what info you actually need in the partial, but you can essentially add whatever you like in this way. Just bear in mind that `ViewData` is a dynamic dictionary, so you'll have to type whatever you get out of it.